# How can i merge header cells in Excel writer in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to merge header cells columns into one cell but when i do that my data also comes in one column. I want my resulting output as per this screenshot attached. Kindly help me for this.

[image: Figure: Excel table]

Answer (score 1):

Are your columns variable? Or you always have the same output schema?

If it's fixed then, I would use a template where the headers are fixed and I start populating from row 5.

Answer (score 0):

> Google Spreadsheet input

If you are using the Spreadsheet input that is not possible on the step.

What I usually do in that kind of situation is to create a row with my headers and hide it so the user don't get confused with two headers. Them the Step will get the result perfectly using the column names provided on first row. (you can use a formula like =b3 there so it changes with the real header. No problem.)

> Excel input

If you are using the Excel input step you can set the sheet to be read from row 2, column 0 and should work fine. =)